# Why does the built-in Quarkus annotation @RolesAllowed() is ignored when it is used in a custom annotation?

Tags: graphql, annotations, quarkus, roles

I use a large list of @RolesAllowed("role1", "role2", "role3" ... ) on classes and methods. To make the code easier to read, I intended to build custom annotations where the lengthy list of @RolesAllowed could be contained. What happened is that @RolesAlowed is ignored and all roles are permitted.
Is there any other way to do it?

Custom annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@RolesAllowed({"role1", "role2", "role3", ...})
public @interface RolesAllowedAdminArea {
}
```

class:

```
@RolesAllowedAdminArea
@GraphQLApi
public class ReceiptTemplateResource {
 .
 .
 .
}
```

Comment: This is not valid. It looks like you are attempting the `@RolesAllowedAdminArea` to be used as a CDI stereotype, but for that
1) you would have to annotate it with `@Stereotype`
2) it wouldn't work anyway because stereotypes only can declare interceptor bindings and some other CDI-related stuff, and `@RolesAllowed` isn't one of those things

Comment: Consider using configuration instead of annotations:
`quarkus.http.auth.policy.graphql-policy.roles-allowed=role1,role2,role3
quarkus.http.auth.permission.graphql.paths=/graphql
quarkus.http.auth.permission.graphql.policy=graphql-policy`

Comment: I appreciate your comment. Since I have various sets of roles in each class and they are lengthy, I require annotations. I am using configuration for base roles that are permitted in all classes. My role model is working. I only need ideas on how to deal with the issue of a lengthy number of roles on multiple classes and methods.